# IIS 502.3 crash but only from Electron

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

**Background:**

- I have an ASP.NET Core application running on IIS 10.
- I have edited my hosts file to point `foo.example.com` to `127.0.0.1`
- My site in IIS is bound to `foo.example.com`

**What happens:**

- From postman, I can perform `GET` and `POST` requests to `foo.example.com`
- From my electron application, I can perform `GET` requests, but equivalent `POST` requests yield `502.3` 
  `The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.`
- When the 502.3 Errors occur, Visual Studio JIT Debugger tells me that `w3wp.exe` suffers an unhandled exception.

**Logged information**

I found some logs that might provide hints at the problem, but unfortunately I could not find my solution by searching these issues:

- Event Viewer - `WAS`

> A process serving application pool 'foo pool' suffered a fatal
>   communication error with the Windows Process Activation Service. The
>   process id was '33560'. The data field contains the error number.

- Event Viewer - `.NET Runtime`

> Application: foo.exe CoreCLR Version: 4.6.28325.1
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an internal error in
>   the .NET Runtime at IP 7A75B0BE (7A5E0000) with exit code c0000005.

- Event Viewer - `Application Error`

> Faulting application name: foo.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x5afb49d6 Faulting module name: coreclr.dll, version:
>   4.6.28325.1, time stamp: 0x5ddbf36b Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0017b0be Faulting process ID: 0x364c Faulting application
>   start time: 0x01d5e1be9f886566 Faulting application path:
>   C:\Users\foo\AppData\Local\foo Ltd...\foo.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.1.15\coreclr.dll Report
>   ID: cef1facf-1cb6-46a9-ac39-cbacca6745c4 Faulting package full name: 
>   Faulting package-relative application ID:

I am unsure what could be causing this error and why it would only be triggered in IIS by an electron application and not from postman?

Answer (score 1):

By attaching the Visual Studio debugger to my Application Pool's process, I was able to discover that this issue was to do with calls to some unmanaged code that triggered an unhandled exception in a third party library. The issue had nothing to do with Electron.